# SQL Mirroring stopping and starting endpoints

Tags: sql, endpoint, error-log

I've been getting Error: 8474, State: 11. (Near endpoint role: Target, far endpoint address: '')  on the mirrored server. Everything has been running fine, all the databases(80+) are in synchronized state.

How can I stop these errors? 
Did anyone stop, start endpoints? will there be any issues if I do that?

Below is the script that I am planning on running:

```
use master
GO
alter endpoint endpoint_name state = stopped;
GO
alter endpoint endpoint_name state = started;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There were no risks, I ran the scripts and everything was up and running in 10 secs